# How to send jsp page as a content of email from servlet?

Tags: jsp, email, servlets

Please do post if you have any code snippets?
When the email is sent out, inbox should have jsp page. Any code snippets?

Comment: I assume you want the email body to be the resultant HTML from the jsp page...not the jsp file itself?

Answer (score 0):

Since the jsp/servlet/chain can be adding dynamic content, the only real way is to grab the resultant HTML from the URL using something like:

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.oracle.com/");
byte[] html;
try (InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
     ByteArrayOutputStream bout = new ByteArrayOutputStream();) {
   byte[] buffer = new byte[512];
   int read = 0;
   while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
       bout.write(buffer, 0, read);
   }
   html = bout.getBytes();
}
```

If you want the HTML as a String:

```
String htmlString = new String(html, StandardCharset.UTF-8);
```

Comment: Hi Steve, I have to read local jsp email template from servlet and send that jsp page as email body. Instead of sending email from servlet using html tags, how can we use jsp templates?